# 2D Ising Model in Python

Tags: python, numpy, physics, montecarlo

I am trying to calculate the energy, magnetization and specific heat of a two dimensional lattice using the metropolis monte carlo algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import random

#creating the initial array
def init_spin_array(rows, cols):
    return np.ones((rows, cols))

#calcuating the nearest neighbours
def find_neighbors(spin_array, lattice, x, y):
    left   = (x, y - 1)
    right  = (x, (y + 1) % lattice)
    top    = (x - 1, y)
    bottom = ((x + 1) % lattice, y)

    return [spin_array[left[0], left[1]],
            spin_array[right[0], right[1]],
            spin_array[top[0], top[1]],
            spin_array[bottom[0], bottom[1]]]

#calculating the energy of the configuration
def energy(spin_array, lattice, x ,y):
    return 2 * spin_array[x, y] * sum(find_neighbors(spin_array, lattice, x, y))


#main code
def main10():
    #defining the number of initial sweeps, the lattice size, and number of monte carlo sweeps
    RELAX_SWEEPS = 50
    lattice = 10
    sweeps = 1000
    e1= e0 = 0
    for temperature in np.arange(0.1, 4.0, 0.2):
        #setting up initial variables
        spin_array = init_spin_array(lattice, lattice)
        mag = np.zeros(sweeps + RELAX_SWEEPS)
        spec = np.zeros(sweeps + RELAX_SWEEPS)
        Energy = np.zeros(sweeps + RELAX_SWEEPS)
        # the Monte Carlo
        for sweep in range(sweeps + RELAX_SWEEPS):
            for i in range(lattice):
                for j in range(lattice):
                    e = energy(spin_array, lattice, i, j)
                    if e <= 0:
                        spin_array[i, j] *= -1
                    elif np.exp((-1.0 * e)/temperature) > random.random():
                        spin_array[i, j] *= -1

            #Thermodynamic Variables 

            #Magnetization
            mag[sweep] = abs(sum(sum(spin_array))) / (lattice ** 2)

            #Energy
            Energy[sweep] = energy(spin_array,lattice,i,j)/ (lattice ** 2)

            #Specific Heat
            e0 = e0 + energy(spin_array,lattice,i,j)               
            e1 = e1 + energy(spin_array,lattice,i,j) *energy(spin_array,lattice,i,j)
            spec[sweep]=((e1/(sweeps*lattice) - e0*e0/(sweeps*sweeps*lattice*lattice)) / (temperature * temperature))

        #Printing the thermodynamic variables    

        print(temperature,sum(Energy[RELAX_SWEEPS:]) / sweeps, sum(mag[RELAX_SWEEPS:]) / sweeps,sum(spec[RELAX_SWEEPS:]) / sweeps)



main10()
```

I appear to be calculating the Magnetization correctly, which makes me convinced that my monte carlo algorithm is correct. But I appear to have some errors when calculating the Total Energy and the Specific Heat. I am trying to think of possible errors for them but I am genuinely struggling!

The graphs of them are shown below.

[image: Energy]

[image: Magnetization]

[image: Specific Heat]

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: This might be better suited to the [Computational Science stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @P.Blah - where do you want this question? Here or on Computational Science? We don't, as a rule, like cross posted questions. If you think it's better asked elsewhere please delete this copy.